# Simulate cancellation token request in RunAsync() at ServiceFabric

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric, cancellation-token

I am trying to use the FabricClient API in order to simulate a graceful failure (like partition/replica/instance restart), but for some reason the service keeps recovering.

The only time where it finally succeeds is when I manually delete the service from the Cluster UI, and then I see it is stuck since RunAsyc is stuck. (I have written a special dummy service which doesn't honor the cancellation token.)

These are my attempts:

```
foreach (var service in Services)
        {
            var partitions = FabricClient.QueryManager.GetPartitionListAsync(service.ServiceName).Result;
            foreach (var partition in partitions)
            {
                var operationGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
                restartOperationsIds.Add(operationGuid);
                var partitionId = partition.PartitionInformation.Id;

                FabricClient.FaultManager.RestartReplicaAsync(
                    ReplicaSelector.PrimaryOf(PartitionSelector.PartitionIdOf(service.ServiceName, partitionId)),
                    CompletionMode.Verify, CancellationToken.None);

                FabricClient.TestManager.StartPartitionRestartAsync(operationGuid,
                    PartitionSelector.PartitionIdOf(service.ServiceName, partitionId),
                    RestartPartitionMode.AllReplicasOrInstances, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
            }
        }
```

RestartReplicaAsync doesn't do anything it seems, while StartPartitionRestartAsync causes the service to appear to restart, but then it succeeds again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cancellation token is cancelled in a few scenarios, and most these scenarios are mainly for maintenance reasons, they might be:

- Upgrades: A service is shutdown to be updated, RunAsync() willbe called when restarted.
- Scaling Down: Replicas are removed on a scale down and RunAsync is not called
- Load Balancing: When SF need to move services around, RunAsync will be called.
- Node Deactivation(Restart\RemoveData): SF will move services to other nodes, triggering the cancellation for graceful shutdown.
- Remove Application\Service: When you remove a service or application from the cluster.

There are some other events where the services are forcefully shutdown, and the token is not called, an example is when you call [`Restart-ServiceFabricDeployedCodePackage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/restart-servicefabricdeployedcodepackage?view=azureservicefabricps) [`Restart-ServiceFabricPartition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/restart-servicefabricpartition?view=azureservicefabricps) or [`Restart-ServiceFabricNode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/restart-servicefabricnode?view=azureservicefabricps)

Comment: According to the docs, partition restart is graceful, so I thought it should do the trick.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-testability-actions

But I understand your input. Will try to simulate one of these scenarios.

Comment: All the three commands I mentioned above, simulates failure with recovery, I don't see the reason a failure would cause the graceful shutdown, regarding the `Restart-ServiceFabricReplica` according to the docs, should just restart the replica of a stateful service in a safe manner calling the cancellation in the token, Might be the case, if the Restart is not safe (Might cause data loss), SF prevent it from happening, an example, is when only one replica is available, shutting down would cause outage to the service. If you change the `CompletionMode.Verify` to other value, might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that another replica becomes primary, without you having to do anything. Restarting a partition results in the restart of all replicas instead of just the primary.

(Not sure what you're trying to accomplish with this. But if you want to do some controlled chaos testing, it's good to know that there are [PowerShell tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/start-servicefabricpartitionrestart?view=azureservicefabricps) that can help you.)